# How to make a right route?

Tags: php, regex, routes, kohana

For example I have this url & route:

```
http://mysite/test/article-1
```

and

```
// Route on Test    
Route::set('Test', 'test/<alias>',array('alias'=>'\D+'))
```

It will work only for `http://mysite/test/article`, how to make it right? And the rule is that alias can't starts with digit.

Comment: You are not looking for how to write a correct route, you are looking for a regex that applies to `article-n`. http://webcheatsheet.com/php/regular_expressions.php seems like a nice resource.

Comment: articles mask can be different, like `my-article` or `justart`

Comment: Well I have tested some things, which do seem to work. If a mask is generated which does not 'fit' you should either update the regex or the algorithm that generates them :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex might be what you are looking for.

`^(?![0-9])([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(-([0-9]+))?`

Some tests:

- article -> TRUE
- article-19 -> TRUE
- article-article-19 -> TRUE
- article19 -> TRUE
- why-are_programmers+developers_on_stack-overflow -> TRUE
- 1article -> FALSE
- 1article-17 -> FALSE